# How to CSS a two column list of items with a title on one side and an image on top of the other side?

Tags: html, css, list

So I'd like to make a 2 column-list with a title on top of one column and the photo on top of the other column.

```
Title  |   _____
       |  |     |
Item 1 |  |     |
Item 2 |  |     |
Item 3 |  |_____|
Item 4 |  Item 8
Item 5 |  Item 9
Item 6 |  Item 10
Item 7 |  Item 11
```

I initially played with ul {columns: 2} and this works really well in terms of responsiveness (the list has 14 items which can balance equally). And then I return to 1 column for mobile layout. I can insert the image (or the title) at the top of the list (inside the first li element) and it still rolls!

Unfortunately inserting both the title and the image within that 2 column layout is where the problems are starting to show up:

- I cannot put the title under the image (or at least that how I feel - and that's also how the original design goes)
- I cannot put the title on the opposite column top as it will change column or position as the browser changes width
- I could start with the title at the beginning of the list, but then I am stuck with that image which will not stay on top of the 2nd column.

So maybe multi-column list is not the way. I've also tried with divs and table but then the number of items is already set per div/table column and they will not automatically switch to the proper column to balance the design.

So I was wondering if this was possible at all in fact, and if not, I'll have to reconsider my approach.

Thank you for any suggestion you may have.

Comment: Should the title, and image, always appear at the top of their respective columns?

Comment: Yes, that's the objective. It's a price list section and placing the image at the end of the list doesn't look nice. Likewise the title should be at the beginning too. The only thing I see now is having the title in full width and the image at the top of the list (that will be my plan B option).

Comment: I better understood your question and fixed the answer, I think it's now exactly what you need. And BTW, using sarcasm in comments is not the way ;)